# awesome_nested_fields not adding new not removing new elements of form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails newb here. I'm trying to use the awesome_nested_fields gem (https://github.com/lailsonbm/awesome_nested_fields) in a simple tasks project. I've followed the instructions found in the link but I can't seem to get the dynamic add or remove item to work as shown in the demo [here](http://phonebook.guava.com.br/plain/people/366/edit). I've been looking through the demo source code and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing incorrectly.  Updating an already existing task works fine.  Please let me know if you need more code my project.

Here is my partial containing the form:

```
<%= form_for(daily_list) do |f| %>
<div class="items">
    <%= f.nested_fields_for :tasks do |f| %>
        <fieldset class="item">
            <%= f.label :title %>
            <%= f.text_field :title %>

            <%= f.label :body %>
            <%= f.text_field :body %>

            <a href="#" class="remove" data-confirm="Are you sure?">remove</a>

            <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
        </fieldset>
    <% end -%>
</div>
<a href="#" class="add">add task</a>

<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update tasks for #{format_date(daily_list.date)}" %>
</div>
```

The only line I've added to my application.js file is the following (besides the necessary require statements):

```
$(document).ready(function(e)) {
  $('FORM').nestedFields();
```

}

Help please! Thank you :)

Comment: Did it send request to server when add task? if so what's the paremters

Comment: Hrm, it doesn't look like it... what's the best way for me to tell?